# the warning message of using exposure.equalize_adapthist in scikit-image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

While performing the Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization, I got the following warning message. How to avoid it and what does it indicate?

```
from skimage import exposure
img_adapteq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(image_gray, clip_limit=0.03)

C:\Users\ugwz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py:135: UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from float64 to uint16
  .format(dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj_out))
```

Comment: As it says, you possibly lost some precision when you applied CLAHE to a `float64` image that you didn't share with us. What's to say? Don't expect the results of applying an operation to a 64-bit float image to fit in a 16-bit image. You can't store 1.8E308 in a space that can only hold up to 65,536.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks, but how can I know whether the image is float64 or not.  It is just a jpg file, and I read it this way, image = imread("C:\\test8.jpg")   image_gray = rgb2gray(image)

Comment: A JPG is normally inherently `uint8` in each channel.

Comment: Try `print(image_gray.dtype)` and `print(image.dtype)` to check the actual types involved.

Answer (score 1):

`rgb2gray` converts your image to float because it is computing relative luminance according to the formula on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance). Note that, due to the conventions of the Scientific Python ecosystem, it also rescales the values to be in [0, 1], so `.astype(np.uint16)` will not do what you want. Instead, use `skimage.util.img_as_{ubyte,uint}`, as detailed in the [scikit-image documentation on data types](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html):

```py
from skimage import color, util, exposure

image = io.imread(<your-filename>)
image_gray = color.rgb2gray(image)
image16 = util.img_as_uint(image_gray)
img_adapteq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(image_gray, clip_limit=0.03)
```

Unfortunately, with version 0.15, you'll still see the warning, but it's been removed in version 0.16 and higher, which should be out in the next few days.

Comment: Thank you for drawing that document to my attention. I will delete any of my comments above which are incorrect and may mislead others.